# A complex limit

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $\omega=Re^{i\alpha}$. Fix $\omega$, we need to find the limit
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow R}\left(\frac{z+\omega}{\omega-z}\right)$$

Thank in advance!

Comment: Assuming that $\theta \not= \alpha$, you can just plug in $R$.  Did you type this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating the interior expression you get:

$ \frac{(w+z)\overline{(w-z)}}{(w-z)\overline{(w-z)}} = \frac{(w+z)(\bar{w}-\bar{z})}{||w-z||²} = \frac{w\bar{w}-w\bar{z}+z\bar{w}-z\bar{z}}{||w-z||²}$

Now using trig identities and values of w and z, it follows:

$ = \frac{R²-r²+Rr(e^{i(\theta-\alpha)}-e^{-i(\theta-\alpha)})}{||w-z||²} = \frac{R²-r²+i2Rr\sin{(\theta-\alpha)}}{||w-z||²}$

Plugging the limit, and computing the norm of w-z by trigonometry:

$ \lim_{r \to R} \frac{(w+z)}{(w-z)} =
 \frac{i2R²\sin{(\theta-\alpha)}}{4R²(\sin{\frac{\theta-\alpha}{2}})²} = 
 \frac{i2\sin{\frac{\theta-\alpha}{2}}\cos{\frac{\theta-\alpha}{2}}}{2(\sin{\frac{\theta-\alpha}{2}})²} = 
i \cot{\frac{\theta-\alpha}{2}} $

The value of the limit goes to infinity for values of $ \theta - \alpha = 2n\pi $, as expected, and is always purely imaginary, as can be seen from geometric considerations.